# what "the degrees to which an individual peer service or goods provider can elect to work for a sharing platform" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

In the following sentence, I'm confused about what "the degrees to which an individual peer service or goods provider can elect to work for a sharing platform" means.

Does it mean something like whether an individual peer service or goods provider can freely choose a sharing platform among many platforms or he(she) have few choices or options(that are worth considering to choose)?

Against the backdrop of liability and tax problems that support strong cooperation between
market platforms and government, the issue of the fair treatment of labor is the thorniest and most
variable aspect of the sharing economy’s maturation. Because of the fl uidity of the employment
relationship and **the degrees to which an individual peer service or goods provider can elect to
work for a sharing platform**, labor protections defy uniform application.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The degrees to which an individual..." means *To What Extent* or *How far will they go* to achieve their goal. I can see how your context mashes this phrase together with others until you are ready to break out the protractor, but neither Degrees nor Radians are used here. The degrees or extent to which a provider can work, is the meaningful part.